# Where in AWS the instances made by docker-machine

Tags: amazon-ec2, docker-machine

Using AWS free tire, I can create instance using GUI and I see it by clicking on Instance menu. I'm using AWS to learn about docker. 
Yesterday I created my first instance remotely, using docker-machine, from the command line. I expected that I could find that as a regular instance in EC2 console, but I failed to find any related instance there. 
Could anyone please tell me where in AWS panel it is located?

Comment: check in the machine where you have installed docker-machine on. You can use the command  "docker-machine ls" on that machine to see your container. The instances that you see by clicking on "Instances" are EC2 instances and not your container. Containers are launched inside an EC2 machine.

Comment: Thank you, but aren't EC2 instance and EC2 machine the same thing? If my "Instances" is empty, and docker-machine used with aws driver, it will create the container, but I can't find where the instance is accessible from EC2 console and since I'm using free tier, I'm not even sure if the created machine is in the free tire limitation!

Comment: can you tell me what command you used to create the instance and the container and on which machine?

Comment: yes please: docker-machine create --driver amazonec2  --amazonec2-vpc-id  vpc-MY-ID  --amazonec2-zone us-east-2a aws77

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just ran into the same problem, here's how I found it.

EC2 shows instances depending on what '*region*' has been selected. Select different regions inside AWS console using the dropdown tab in the top right corner of your screen. By default, instances created by `docker-machine` end up in us-east-1 (N. Virginia).